# How do I plot 2-dimensional data in circles where radius representing the 3rd column and the color representing the 4th column?

Tags: colors, gnuplot

Here is an example data set.

```
#x y r c
1 2 10 2
3 1 2 4
3 2 1 5
```

I can plot with circle's radius representing the 3rd column OR with color representing the 3rd column. However, I don't know how to keep them both in the plot.

Here is my code to plot with radius representing the 3rd column.

```
plot 'rslt.log' u 1:2:3 w points pt 7 ps variable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
plot 'rslt.log' u 1:2:3:4 w points pt 7 ps variable lc palette
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is:

```
plot 'test.dat' u 1:2:3:4 w p pt 7 ps variable lc variable
```

or using the circles linestyle:

```
plot 'test.dat' u 1:2:3:4 w circles linecolor variable
```

If you want solid filled circles:

```
plot 'test.dat' u 1:2:3:4 w circles linecolor variable fillstyle solid
```

---

For any of the above, you can substitute `linecolor variable` with `linecolor palette` as suggested by @andyras.  The difference is that `palette` maps a floating point number onto the palette whereas `variable` maps the integer to a linestyle which has a color associated with it.

With `ps variable` the number in the associated column becomes a multiplicative factor which increases the default size of the point.  With circles you have the freedom to specify the exact size of the circle (as the radius) -- Although I'm not 100% sure which axis is used in the common case where the aspect ratio of your plot isn't 1.